# How to start many (100+) instances of program in Java?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm making an order system with design patterns of integration for a school assignment. A client can place an order and the intermediary than broadcasts a supplyRequest to all suppliers(100+), which have code in it that generates random productcodes that are in stock. The fastest supplier gets chosen for the client.

To simulate and test this I need to run 100 instances of my Supplier class. In IntelliJ you can run classes with a main method bij right-clicking on it and clicking run. How can i do this in a way that it launches 100 times the class? Or how would men approach this kind of simulation?

If this isn't possible in IntelliJ, should i then write a bash script or something to launch a compiled program many times?

Or are there specific tools for such a situation?

Thanks in advance,

Mike

Comment: Why would you need 100+ instances? Why wouldn't 2 or 3 or even 5 instances work for your simulation? Another question is does you machine even support 100+ instances given the configuration of your machine if you go on that route?

Comment: Try to run 1 instance of the program that will run each `supplier` in a separate thread

Comment: It sounds like you're confusing multiple different types of testing.  To test that it _works_, I'd do as @Ruslan above suggests and have a multi-threaded thing going on.  To test the _performance_ is a whole other kettle of fish; profiling, using representative hardware, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you possibly just create a test class and just run the code you need to simulate 100 times? You said you already have the random generation complete, so couldn't you just loop the functions you need 100 times?

Otherwise yes, you can create a bash script to run your jar 100 times if you need to.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned design patterns, have you looked at "Enterprise Integration Patterns" ?

You could use the `recipient list` pattern in this case.

Here is an example using Apache Camel framework.

http://camel.apache.org/recipient-list.html

Otherwise, if you want to write it in plain Java, you can use java stream api... create a list of id's (1..100), stream the list... and process each id individually.

You wont be running 100 instances of your program, you will run one instance, and either you will process them 100 id's sequentially or *in parallel*.

Good luck.

Comment: yes, those are the patterns I looked at. I also saw the recipient list pattern, but I didn't know how that could fit in my case. Because the recipient list would then have to know which supplier has which products, so you are managing a list of supplier with the products they can supply. Every supplier already has a list of products they have in it's class. Isn't that redundant? And if not, should all the suppliers broadcast their inventory to the intermediary periodly? Or is it simpler to hardcode it in the intermediary which supplier has what, to limit the amount of consumers?

Comment: Actually the recipient list doesnt know anything about which supplier has which products... it just routes to supplier 43 or 59 or whatever. Each supplier should then know its own product list... you can do a filtering here if you like. Try to break your program into components. List generator -> recipient list -> supplier component -> aggregator.

Comment: Let me first thank you for the answers. I thought the recipient list has some business rules that specifies to which supplier an order product get's routed. Every supplier has some random productcodes in it's inventory and the intermediary want's to pick out the fastest deliverytime for the client. So for me to implement the recipient list pattern I then need to think about business rules for determining where to route supplyRequests. I hope you understand my thoughts. I've made a design: https://imgur.com/dGrMCR9.

Comment: Looks fantastic! Good luck onwards.